# Service-worker and tracking

Tags: service-worker

To protect (at least a bit) from tracking one could disable third party cookies in the browser.

How to prevent from being tracked by service-workers left by ads (running in iframes)?

If I understand this right then it's possible that service-workers modify any request sent to such an ad site (even if the request originates from an iframe). So the service worker could add some 'identifier' to the request header which would offer the same tracking possibilities as the blocked cookies.

Comment: After playing around a bit it seems that Chrome only allows service workers from inside an iframe when 3. party cookies are enabled.

Firefox behaves differently: service workers can be used independently of the 3. party cookie settings - which looks like a bug when comparing to the much better Chrome behavior